# Appending to excel, but posts the same line two times. c#

Tags: c#, excel, duplicates

I'm appending to excel, but when I post, i find that the same line has been posted twice. so i have 2 lines. when i post again, it leaves my first line, overwrites the second line, but then gives me a duplicate again as a 3rd line.

So all in all, I can post all i need and am just left with 1 duplicate line.
i cant seem to correct it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook mWorkBook;
        private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets mWorkSheets;
        private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet mWSheet1;
        private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Combo1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string path = @"C:\Users\Staff\Desktop\RIT\worksheet.xls";
            oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = true;
            oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
            mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false,             
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0,       
   true, false, false);

            mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;

            mWSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = mWSheet1.UsedRange;

            //I thought issue maybe here.. 

            int colCount = range.Columns.Count;
            int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;
            for (int index = 1; index < 3; index++) 
            {
                mWSheet1.Cells[rowCount + index, 1] = rowCount + index;
                mWSheet1.Cells[rowCount + index, 1] = Combo1 + index;
            }

            mWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
               Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
               Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
               Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
               Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            mWorkBook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            mWSheet1 = null;
            mWorkBook = null;
            oXL.Quit();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try using `int index = 2; index > 0; index--` instead => unless you will re-process the freshly inserted line within the next iteration. This causes the double insert.

Comment: Have you tried it? Does my proposed change work?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. If i put 0, 1 or 2, it doesnt post anything at all. form still opens and works. excel opens, saves and closes. but nothing is posted.

Comment: Then please add more code because theoretically it has to work. Without you sharing more code this is a guessing game. Because the reason why it does not work is then in the code you didn't share! Thanks.

Comment: Appologies, i copied an pasted your change, i missed the ">" out. its working perfect now. thank you!

Comment: I've added it as an answer with deep explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
for (int index = 2; index > 0; --index)
{
    //...
}
```

instead of your for-loop because you would process the new inserted/appended line in the next iteration of the loop. Thus the line is inserted twice and it will get overwritten the next time the loop starts (as you mentioned).

You also use this kind of loop (I'd call it high-to-low loop) when deleting something from an array: there you would occur the following:

- you have an array with item0, item1 and item2
- you start processing the array from index 0
- if a condition passes (let's appose it does at index 0) you delete item0 from the array
- then you increase the counter.

What happened?

- you just deleted item0

Everything's fine untill here:

- you now have item1 at index 0
- you now have item2 at index 1
- your counter is at index 1 already

So you skipped item1 from processing.

The same has happened to you in the vice versa way: you have added a line and increased the counter by one which made you beeing in the newly inserted/added line.

Answer (score 0):

All values can be assigned at once:

```
object[,] values = { { rowCount + 1, Combo1 + 1 }, { rowCount + 2, Combo1 + 2 } };

mWSheet1.Cells.Resize[2, 2].Offset[rowCount].Value2 = values;
```